# Can the word 'undress' be used to describe breaking down a situation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a campaign around a disease and the patients' wanting to live a normal life i.e. going topless at the beach, swimming with friends, etc.

My thinking is "***[Disease name]* Undressed**" - meaning we break down everything you need to know about the disease and give you all the information you need to take your disease into your own hands through various resources etc. etc.

I'm sure I've heard "let's undress the situation" before, but cannot seem to find anything online!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect that using "undressed" will evoke, possibly unwanted, sexual connotations.

Comment: I agree with @KillingTime, personally I find "let's undress this man" when you're trying to uncover details about him would be ambiguous and awkward. I would use "let's educate ourselves about this man" or something similar in that context.

Comment: You probably misheard "let's undress the situation", because it would be a very strange thing to say.

Comment: Idioms tend to be pretty inflexible. 'Kick the bucket' but never 'kick the pail'.  'Covid / AIDS / ... unveiled' is the usual metaphor. // You need to add an actual reference or two, like 'No signs of 'undress' used for 'demystified / revealed ...' found under 'undress' in Durham Dictionary or Macdonald's Dictionary'.

Comment: I wonder if the use of *undress* in this context is a mistaken hearing of *address* - situations are often addressed, rarely undressed.

Comment: Why is the question off-topic? I cannot see anything that would be off-topic within the question; it is asking about the usage of an English word in certain circumstances, so I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: @ThisFieldIsRequired
 Lack of signs of research (as I suggest above). "I've not found anything" is insufficient without named texts.

Comment: "Going topless at the beach" is living a normal life?? That is definitely a state of undress...

Comment: Stay simple: "**The bare facts about [name of disease]**".

Comment: *Unpack” is the usual idiom.

Comment: You most likely heard 'unpack,' not undress

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use "undress" in this context.

Try something like:

- Everything you need to know about X
- X: FAQ
- Living with X
- X explained
- X: Basic facts

Comment: I'd say "Living with X" comes with its own set of difficulties, but the rest of your alternatives are great.

Comment: Thank you for saying undress does not work here. I suggest: [x}: Basic Facts

Answer (score 2):

"[X] Undressed" and its variations have been used in titles, sometimes, but not always, in a tongue-in-cheek/provocative fashion, for example when the subject involves dress, sexuality, the human body, etc. It also appears to be used with the connotation of "stripping the subject bare." Below are some examples (two of the books were published by Oxford and Cambridge University Presses and two papers were published in *Nature*).

Personally, I think a title like "Psoriasis  Undressed" is worth consideration, especially if the purpose is to explain the disease and its treatments to a lay public, helping those with the condition gain self-confidence. Photos used in the campaign would help emphasize the two meanings of "undressed."

*However, if the disease does not have dermatological symptoms (e.g., depression) and your goal is simply to improve patients' conditions so they get out of the house more, I would stay away from "undressed."*

**undress** (v.)

> EXPOSE entry 1, REVEAL
>
> *But the combination of Adele’s authenticity, her natural beauty, her unparalleled vocal talent and her willingness to undress her deepest
> emotions in song, coalesced for a special that felt exactly that –
> special.* — Melissa Ruggieri, *USA TODAY*, 16 Nov. 2021 [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undress#examples)

> To strip or divest of or as if of a covering; expose:
>
> *undress a pretense* [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/undress)

---

> In the later Middle Ages clothing was used to mark religious,
> military, and chivalric orders; in the courtly milieu, more
> specifically, the ostentatious display of luxury dress was used as a
> means of self-definition for the ruling elite. In *Courtly Love
> Undressed*, E. Jane Burns explores the representation of this material
> culture in the literary texts and other documents that imagine various
> functions for elite clothing in twelfth- and thirteenth-century
> France. [Blurb for E. Jane Burns; *Courtly Love **Undressed***](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.9783/9780812291247/html)  (2002)

(A number of other works have "Courtly Love Undressed" in the title.)

> *Exoticisation Undressed* is an innovative ethnography that makes visible the many layers through which our understandings of indigenous
> cultures are filtered and their inherent power to distort and refract
> understanding. The book focuses in detail on the clothing practices of
> the Emberá in Panama, an Amerindian ethnic group, who have gained
> national and international visibility through their engagement with
> indigenous tourism. [Blurb for Dimitrios Theodossopoulos;
> *Exoticisation **Undressed**: Ethnographic nostalgia and authenticity in Emberá clothes*](https://www.manchesterhive.com/view/9781526100955/9781526100955.xml) (2016)

> This study investigates the spatiotemporal dynamics associated with
> conscious and non-conscious processing of naked and dressed human
> bodies. [L. Legrand et al.; "Basic Instinct **Undressed**: Early
> Spatiotemporal Processing for Primary Sexual Characteristics" in
> *PLOS ONE*](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0069726) (2013)

> Ethnic conflict is not—because there are no ethnic groups in conflict.
> This is the main conclusion of a comparison of so-called “ethnic
> conflicts” in the Balkans and in colonial India. A comparison of
> Muslim nation building in these two regions provides several valuable
> insights that go far beyond the specific cases. Thus far, there have
> been many hints in the literature on similarities between Bosnia and
> Pakistan or the Balkans and the Indian subcontinent as a whole. But
> there have been no systematic comparisons, though many parallels
> emerge when we look more closely. [Carsten Wieland; '“Ethnic Conflict”
> **Undressed**: Patterns of Contrast, Interest of Elites, and Clientelism of Foreign Powers in Comparative Perspective—Bosnia,
> India, Pakistan'](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/nationalities-papers/article/abs/ethnic-conflict-undressed-patterns-of-contrast-interest-of-elites-and-clientelism-of-foreign-powers-in-comparative-perspectivebosnia-india-pakistan/906D301FA94704243A8D71BF71CCD0EE) (2018)

> Fragile chemical groups can be shielded from harsh reaction conditions
> by temporary protection. This approach is conventional wisdom for
> organic synthesis, but is it always the best solution? [John Porco;
> "Synthesis **undressed**" in *Nature* 21 March 2007](https://www.nature.com/articles/446383a)

> We have categorized the mainstream theories of perfect and imperfect
> competition as fakery with evident misrepresentational intent. In the
> section on methodology, we implied that it would be legitimate to
> ***undress* the subject** under investigation in order to dress it up again in thought.  [Charles Wheelan; *Naked Economics: **Undressing**
> the Dismal Science*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alternative_Theories_of_Competition/Q6v3-E9B4tsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22undress%20the%20subject%22&pg=PA74&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> One of mankind's most enduring questions is the legitimate scope of
> state power: how far and in what ways may the government meddle with
> people's lives? Where lies the line that government ought not cross?
> [Jethro Lieberman; *Liberalism **Undressed***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Liberalism_Undressed/WAdmkFTobe8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=undressed&pg=PP2&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

> [Thomas Conners; "Javanese **undressed**" in D. Gil and A. Schapper
> (eds.) *Austronesian **Undressed***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Austronesian_Undressed/65EBEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=undressed&pg=PA253&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> [Amanda Murphy; "The Empress **Undressed**: Dress, Disguise, and the
> Next Generation in Pushkin's Prose" in *The Russian Review*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/russ.12155) (2017)

> [Richard D. Averitt; "Quasiparticles **undressed**" in *Nature*](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys826)
> (2008)

> [Eric Bronson; "The Myth of Resilience: Ajax **Undressed**" in
> *Mosaic* vol. 52, n.4](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/745263/summary) (2019)

> [Dale Barbour; "**Undressed** Toronto: The Transformation of Bathing,
> 1850 to 1935"](https://www.proquest.com/openview/1be098e0b279ff2ba186d54e3dbc97d5/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=18750) (2018) [Dissertation]

Comment: I agree that "'Psoriasis Undressed' is worth consideration ... ." +1 Also, your mention of "stripping the subject **bare** " makes me think that "Psoriasis laid bare" might also be worth considering.

Comment: "psoriasis undressed" really bothers me since people who have it are especially sensitive about being in a state of undress where everyone can see their skin. For pity's sake.

Comment: I assume that would be the purpose of the OP's campaign–so patients know their condition can improve with treatment and that they can lead a more normal life.

Comment: You can cite as many uses as you like. You won't find one where it says a disease is undressed. Not one of your hits has anything at all to do with diseases. In fact, "psoriasis" undressed is LOL. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

An idiomatic term would be "*unravelled*". However, using it with the name of the disease would cause a certain ambiguity as it would be interpreted as only a claim to explain the disease itself.

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unravel)) If you unravel a mysterious, unknown, or complicated subject, you make it known or understood, and if it unravels, it becomes known or understood:
> We have a long way to go before we unravel the secrets of genetics.

([ref. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Crochet_Unravelled/ZZaroAEACAAJ?hl=fr)) Crochet Unravelled: A Clear and Concise Guide to Learning

([ref. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Leadership_Unravelled/Pwo1EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22unravelled%22&pg=PP1&printsec=frontcover)) Leadership Unravelled: The Faulty Thinking Behind Modern Management

- "Living with [Disease name] Unravelled"

Comment: Doesn't 'unravel' mean something closer to 'uncomplicate'?

Comment: unravel is for thing that are, by definition, tangled.

Comment: @Lambie Matter of opinion then from your point of view ?   the Cambridge dictionary is clear: "complicated subject".

Comment: @Joachim  "Uncomplicate", yes, but through explanation, not through simplification.

Comment: One does not unravel a disease. One unravels a topic.

Comment: @Lambie I tend to think as you do, but  the following constructions can be found (and others that are similar): Britain unravelled — **Cancer: The Metabolic Disease Unravelled (2020)** — The Chemistry Tangle Unravelled: Being Chemistry — **Autism Unravelled Conference: The Biology of Autism : Unravelled (2001)**, Electronics Unravelled: A New Commonsense Approach — The DNA of lettuce unravelled — Unravelling Complexities In Genetics And Genomics, Unravelling Genes —  Notice, however, that in my construction what is unravelled is not the disease but "living" (with a disease).